# Table structure to store a an array of tags per entry

Tags: postgresql, schema, array

Lets say one wants to create a DB to store items, each having a `Set<String> tags`, associated with it. A straightforward way would be a flat table with ItemID, ItemName, DateCreated,... and a `Set<String> tags`. This is going to be inefficient for requests

`Select * from MyTable where tags like '%my_tag%'`

What is the efficient way to store these tags? Should I create a single (huge) table with a compound key `ItemID || tag_number || tag`, or should I create a lot of small tables, each storing tags for a given item?

Will the answer change if I use PostrgeSQL?

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: What is `tags like '%my_tag%'` supposed to mean?  Are you trying to look for a partial match on any tag, or are you searching for a complete tag within some kind of delimited string?